# 3D objects click event in ARCore

Tags: arcore

How to get click event of 3D object rendered using arcore SDK in android studio? 
My requirement  is to click that 3D object and show pop up dialog.

Comment: Are you coding in pure OpenGL? If so, then you'll have to manually perform a ray casting and bounding box check for intersection. Otherwise, you should consider using a higher level rendering framework like Viro: https://viromedia.com/ which manage the rendering and provide helper functions to do ray casting and simple events for you.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ARCore. The game engine / framework that you are using is actually responsible for that.

For example, if you are using Unity, you can use Raycasting.

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = yourARCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
     // Check if what is hit is the desired object
     if(hit.tag == "The_Tag_Of_The_Object_You_Are_Looking_For")
     {
           // User clicked the object.. Do something here..
     }
}
```

Read more here:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/raycasting
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is not supporting this feature. You need to do it by yourself. Most popular way is ray picking method. There is a lot of examples how to use it

Comment: a link to those examples would be great.

Comment: Can you please provide me some relevant examples or  some sample codes that you have done in your projects.I have searched but couldn't get exact solutions of my problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't get me wrong but it is not hard to find such examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746211/android-opengles-2-ray-picking-from-touch-coordinates-unprojecting-calculation

This probably won't solve your problem in 100% because most of the elements must be related with your code and you did not provide any.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Arcore - Sceneform SDK, after creating the anchor, you simple have to set a listener on your AnchorNode like so

```
anchorNode.setOnTapListener((hitResult,motionEvent)->{
   //Your pop up
});
```

Comment: SceneForm made that so easy!