# Android : handle click on 3D object arcore, android studio - JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on an AR Application for Android with Google ArCore SDK (using Android Studio and Java). I have a problem to handle invents : tap or clic on displayed image/3D Object, weither it is about Augmented images or placing a permanent anchor.
Please do you have any example of how to handle click on 3D object in Android Studio?
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855853/3d-objects-click-event-in-arcore

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It not about gaming. Since 2018 there no news about Android Studio handling click évent or a kind of, on 3D object by using ArCore SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through deep research, I found out that there is an open existing project for sceneform that is still working.

You can find the project here :
https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android

and some Android Java samples there :
https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android/tree/master/samples

But pay attention, it seems that some methods in samples are deprecated. I'm working on integrating this in my Augmented Image project but I have some trouble finding corresponding new methods for some of them.

I will appreciate any help from someone who has already done it.

Answer (score 1):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855853/3d-objects-click-event-in-arcore):

> ARCore is not supporting this feature. You need to do it by yourself.

The most recommended method is use of ray casting. Assuming you're using OpenGL, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746211/android-opengles-2-ray-picking-from-touch-coordinates-unprojecting-calculation) describes some methods of using ray casting in the way you need.